# TileStache Dynamic query based on zoom level

Tags: postgis, web-mapping, tilestache

I wanted to make tilestache to be able have a different query for different zoom level.
For certain zoom level I wanted TileStache to query from different postgres table.
How can I achieve this? Is this even possible in TileStache?

Answer (score 3):

To use different queries for different zoom levels you will have to provide queries for each zoom level that you want to use, I think it should be able to query from a different table as well, since we are only defining the database in the `kwargs`.

I have it working using this layer in the `cfg`

```
"roads":
    {       
        "allowed origin":"*",
        "projection": "spherical mercator",
        "provider":
        {
            "class": "TileStache.Goodies.VecTiles:Provider",                        
            "kwargs":
            {
                "dbinfo":
                    {
                       "host":"localhost",
                       "user":"postgres",
                       "password":"postgres123",
                       "database":"test"                       
                    },
                "queries":
                {
                    "7":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4) -- zoom 7+",
                    "8":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4)",
                    "9":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4)",
                    "10":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4)",
                    "11":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4,3,2)",
                    "12":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4,3,2)",
                    "13":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4,3,2)",
                    "14":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads  -- zoom 14+"
                }

            }
        },
        "preview":{"ext":"json"}
    }
```

Leaving the zoom level 0-6 blank will make `TileStache` assume them as `null` and the last query will run on all the zoom levels that follow.

Comment: is it possible to do the same with data from different databases ? because I have tried and its not working

Comment: in the same layer or in different layers?

Comment: For the same layer.

Comment: You cant have data from different databases in the same layer